# How to fetch SPEED Dial contact list in Android?

Tags: android, speed-dial

My question is that SPEED DIAL list shows speed dial contacts list. I want to fetch this SPEED DIAL contact list in my application.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [ContactsContract.Contact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) ,you can do something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, "starred=?",
new String[] {"1"}, null);
```

where the starred=? will be your filter and "1" would suggest to pick up only favorites.

Instead of the hardcoded string "starred", you can use `ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED`